# Textbook Confusion: I hope somebody could clear this up for me (Topic: Second Order Non-Homogenous Equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

So I feel like this chart is written wrong or maybe I'm just reading the Notes section wrong. 
For example, if you look at the characteristic equation of $y"-2y'-3y = -3te^{-t}$ (which is a problem that I am currently working on), you will see that $0$ is not a root at all. Therefore $s = 0$ according to the chart. However, when you work out a particular solution which would be denoted as $yp(t)$, one would see that $s = 1$ since $s = 0 would yield a term (in the particular solution) that is a solution to the homogenous solution (which, of course, cannot be the case). So am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to include the chart?

Comment: what is $s$ exactly ?

Comment: According to the chart, your equation belongs to the second case since zero is not a root of the characteristic equation. You don't have either complex numbers as solution. So second case is correct and $s=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The book consider three cases. When 0 is a solution. It's not the case here. When $\alpha$ is a solution. Here we have $\alpha=-1$. So s is the number of time $\alpha$ ( and not 0)  is a root of the homogeneous equation. Here $s=1$  for $\alpha=-1$ :

$$ y''-2y'-3y = -3te^{-t} $$
The characteristic polynomial is: 
$$r^2-2r-3=0 \implies (r+1)(r-3)=0$$
$$\implies S_r= \{-1,3\}$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is:
$$y(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{3t}$$
For the particular solution a good guess is since $s=1$ ( -1 is a root of the homogeneous equation with multiplicity 1):
$$y_p=t(At+B) e^{-t}$$

Comment: This ^^^ explains it really well. Thank you!

Comment: @darthmaulxxx0.5xxx you're welcomed....There are three cases and you are in the second case where the roots is not zero nor complex. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If it were not for the presence of $y=e^{-t}$ as a comlementary solution, you could take $$y_p=Ate^{-t}+Be^{-t}$$. To avoid overlap of complementary and particular solutions, multiply by$t$ i.e. let $$y_p=At^2e^{-t}+Bte^{-t}$$ Find A and B such that $$y_p''-2y_p'+3y_p=-3te^{-t}.$$ The general solution is $$y=Ce^{-t}+De^{3t}+At^2e^{-t}+Bte^{-t}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could make life easier starting with $y=z\, e^{-t}$ which, after simplifications, gives
$$z''-4z'=-3t$$ So, reduction of order
$$p'-4p=-3t \implies p=c_1 e^{4 t}+\frac{3 t}{4}+\frac{3}{16}$$ which looks to be simple to integrate.

I suppose that is is clear that, beside $c_2$, we shall find terms  in $t$ and $t^2$. Finish for $z$ and go back to $y$.